# Ordered List with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How can I add css class in (* this *) li-s with jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li>*this*</li>
<ol>
    <li></li>
     <li></li>
</ol>
    <li>*this*</li>
<ol>
    <li></li>
     <li></li>
</ol>
</ul>
```

Comment: That isn't valid html , `<ol>` can't be child of `<ul>`. Please provide proper structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

$('ul > li').addClass('className');

Answer (score 0):

Assuming proper valid structure is :

```
<ul>
    <li>*this*
        <ol>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>*this*
        <ol>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use:

```
$('ul').children().addClass('someClass');
```

You should give the `<ul>` a class or id for more specific targeting of the selector so as to not affect any other `<ul>` in page also

Answer (score -1):

Loop through the elements, and check the text attribute:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yftaLtxr/1/

```
var els = $('li');
console.log(els);

for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
{
    var li = $(els[i]);

    var text = li.text();
    if(text == "*this*")
    {
        li.addClass("test");
    }
    console.log(li.attr('class'));
}
```

Comment: But the text is different I was just pointing to which (li) I should give a class.